# kgdb cannot find the source code when debugging kernel module

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module, kgdb

I want to debug a kernel module with kgdb,do as the following:

gdb: add-symbol-file /home/gaoqiang/kernel-32/fs/ext4/ext4.ko 0xffffffffa0122000 -s .bss 0xffffffffa016b380 -s .data 0xffffffffa0168400

gdb: break ext4_getattr
gdb: c

I successfully get to the break point,but gdb told me :"[ No Source Available ]"  then 
how to get gdb to find source code for the module?

Comment: Is it a kernel you have built or a kernel provided by your Linux distro? For the latter, the debug info GDB needs can actually be in a separate file rather than in ext4.ko itself. You can look for the packages like kernel-\*-debug, kernel-\*-debuginfo, etc., in the repositories of your distro.

Comment: BTW, could you describe a bit what you are trying to find out about ext4 with kgdb? In some cases, there could be easier ways to collect the data you need than using a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

As per your problem

`(gdb) add-symbol-file /home/gaoqiang/kernel-32/fs/ext4/ext4.ko 0xffffffffa0122000 -s .bss     0xffffffffa016b380 -s .data 0xffffffffa0168400`

I assume that the module is present in the directory /home/gaoqiang/kernel-32/fs/ext4/. If your source code is also in directory the gdb would not have given the error/warning.

So if the source files for `ext4.ko` module say `ext4.c` and the rest are not present in that directory, copy them to the directory.

Answer (score 1):

```
 (gdb)set solib-search-path /home/gaoqiang/kernel-32/fs/ext4/
```